# Swift: Google Map code throwing nil exception

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

[image]I have the following code and it should basically detect location (if location services are on), then goes back to previous page and shows the coordinates (when button clicked).

@IBOutlet var mapView:GMSMapView!// Adding Google Map check on Storyboard
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var viewController  : ViewController! //to save the object of previous controller to send the location back

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    locationManager = CLLocationManager() // Intialize the location manager
    locationManager.delegate = self

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Methos to change the MApType
@IBAction func changeMaptoEarthView()
{
    self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite
}

@IBAction func changeMaptoMapView()
{
    self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
}
//Method to get UserLocation
@IBAction func sendLocationtoPreviousView()
{
    viewController.locationRecieved(locationManager.location)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backSegue", sender: nil)
}

@IBAction func addUserLocation() //Detect location click event
{
    if(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse) // If already have location access
    {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Denied)// If location access is denied in setting
    {
        UIAlertView(title: "Permission", message: "Please allow location services in setting", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "ok").show()
    }
    else
    {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() // Ask user permission if permission not given
    }
}

//CLLocation Manager Delegate methoda
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {

        self.mapView.clear() // clear all overlay on Map
        self.mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
        // Adding pin on Current location
        var marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = location.coordinate
        marker.snippet = "My Location"
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
        marker.map = mapView

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

The app works in simulator until I say go back, then it throws nil error message on this line:

```
    viewController.locationRecieved(locationManager.location)
```

What could be the reason? I can see the pin on the map although the map is not showing any graphics except google logo below

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see the map graphic in your view (subclass of GMSMapView), this is because of the Google map API key , maybe you have not set it yet in your app delegate or its not set correctly !

make sure you have set the correct google API key with you app bundle id and your account in google .  you have to set below code in your app delete , did didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function :

```
import GoogleMaps

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
          GMSServices.provideAPIKey("your API Key")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `location` property on `CLLocationManager` is an Optional - meaning that it can be nil. According to the docs, it will be nil if no location data has ever been retrieved.

You don't show how `viewController.locationRecieved` is defined, but my guess is that you've configured the `CLLocation` argument to an implicitly unwrapped optional (i.e., with a "!"). Passing nil to such an argument will cause a crash.

Comment: Yes that's the reason for it but still can't figure the fix

Comment: Change the "!" to "?" for the argument to `viewController.locationRecieved` and test for the nil case inside that method.

Comment: I still couldn't figure out why its nil.

Comment: According to the documentation, it will be nil if no location data has been retrieved for some reason.